# My Anchor tag redirects to my own Wordpress site/"the link I gave in Tag"

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget

I am adding social icons using the Raw HTML widget in WordPress. When I add an image and the link to social account the page redirects to my own site/"the social link I entered."
For example, my site is "abc.com", and I added the link of Facebook.com. It is redirecting me to "abc.com/Facebook.com". Please Help.
Thanks

**My Code:**

```
<div style="float:right;padding-right:10px;">
<a href="www.facebook.com">
<img src="http:/abc.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/facebook.png" alt="[Social Account]" width="30" 
 height="30"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `https://` to your link.

```html
<div style="float:right;padding-right:10px;">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">
<img src="http:/abc.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/facebook.png" alt="[Social Account]" width="30" 
 height="30"></a>
</div>
```